# play audio stream when bluetooth connects

Tags: python, bluetooth, script, pulseaudio

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W and want it to use as an Internet Radio. So I wrote a Python script that connects to my bluetooth speaker and starts a stream. Everything works fine, but i always need to login and start the script.

Now I would love to play that stream **automatically when the bluetooth speaker is turned on** but have no clue how to do this.
Maybe someone can help me, so that the Pi permanently scans for the speaker and starts to play the stream?

Here is my script so far:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

def blue_it():
    status = subprocess.call('ls /dev/input/event0 2>/dev/null', shell=True)
    while status == 0:
        print("Bluetooth UP")
        print(status)
        time.sleep(5)
    subprocess.call('mplayer http://addressToSomeStream.com', shell=True)
        status = subprocess.call('ls /dev/input/event0 2>/dev/null', shell=True)
    else:
        waiting()

def waiting():
    subprocess.call('killall -9 pulseaudio', shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    subprocess.call('pulseaudio --start', shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    status = subprocess.call('ls /dev/input/event0 2>/dev/null', shell=True)  
    while status == 2:
        print("Bluetooth DOWN")
        print(status)
        subprocess.call('~/scripts/autopair', shell=True)
        time.sleep(15)
        status = subprocess.call('ls /dev/input/event0 2>/dev/null', shell=True)
    else:
        blue_it() 

blue_it()
```

Comment: Here's a detailed example: [Run a script .py as a service](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=197513)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is how do I auto-boot this script on the pizero. If it is, then the recognised way is via command line to 
sudo nano /etc/profile

and after last 'fi'

type 
sudo python3 /.....your file path and full file name

Then save this via control X ...Y
Pi zero will now autoboot this script every time it restarts.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `rc.local` file. Write this command in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Now at the end of the file, write this:

```
python3 path/to/file.py
```

Now press `ctrl+x` followed by `y` and hit `enter`.
Then reboot your pi.
Now your code will run automatically after every start-up.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: Okay. I'll take care in future. But I think everyone here is  expected to provide a better solution to the main question instead of finding problem in existing answers and down-vote them.

Comment: It's really time to forget this old deprecated error prone stuff and learn how to use systemd Units. An answer with a Unit file could be a good exercise.